# Can I change the font-size?

Tags: jquery-terminal

I've tried changing the font size using things like:

## terminal { font-size: 2em; }

but that just messes up the jquery terminal display. It isn't clear that it's been built to support this.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at their [`jquery.terminal.css`](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/css/jquery.terminal.css), you should be able to do something like:

```
.terminal div{
  margin-bottom: 10px;    
}

.terminal-output, .cmd{
  font-size: 2em !important;
}
```

UPDATE: Since each line in the terminal corresponds to a `<div>` with a fixed [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height), you can increase the spacing between each line by setting `margin-bottom` of each `<div>`. Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/g1xLefbb/).

Also, if the garbles you saw is caused by the "Greetings" section, you might wanna specify your own.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. It just garbles the page as the line-height and other aspects aren't properly handled.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a fiddle. See if that works for you.

Comment: Can i use this terminal to connect to any host?  i am trying to enter ssh command to connect remote server, but looks like this is not full example

Comment: Still broken when some multiline output is printed.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old but for future reference, to change the size of the terminal you can use this css (it will be hard to change size using em's)

```
.terminal, .cmd, .terminal .terminal-output div div, .cmd .prompt {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
```

or if you don't care about IE <strike>or Edge</strike> you can use this (from version 1.0):

```
.terminal {
  --size: 2;
}
```